# Limits problem involving greatest integer function and an unknown function.

Tags: calculus, limits

Given that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^{2}} = 2$, find $\lim_{x \to 0} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor$ and find if $\lim_{x \to 0} \lfloor \frac{f(x)}{x} \rfloor$ exists.
My math teacher says that since the denominator in the first limit is non negative and the limit itself is positive, he says that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0^{+}$ and thus $\lim_{x \to 0} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor = 0$. I find this acceptable but my friend assumes $f(x) = 2x^{2} + \infty^{-}x^{3}$ and claims that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^{2}} = 2$ but that $\lim_{x \to 0} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor$ does not exist as $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = 0^{+}$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f(x) = 0^{-}$.
So who's right and who's wrong? If either of the two are wrong please explain why?

Comment: If $f(x)=2x^2$, does it satisfy any of either of your claims?

Comment: Your math teacher is correct.

Comment: Thanks for answering Andrew Chew! If $f(x) = 2x^{2}$ then quite obviously, $\lim_{x \to 0} frac{f(x)}{x^{2}} = 2$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor = 0$. But the problem is that $f(x)$ can be $2x^{2}$ or it can be any other expression that satisfies $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^{2}} = 2$. We need to find what value $\lim_{x \to 0} \lfloor f(x) \rfloor$ equals irrespective of the function $f(x)$, as long as it satisfies $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^{2}} = 2$.

Comment: Paramanand Singh, I appreciate your effort but can you give the reason as to why my friend was wrong?

Comment: Oh what I would give if tomorrow I'd wake up and find everyone has *stopped* plugging $\infty$ into expressions and treating it as though it were a number!

Comment: Although given that.... I can't even see where that $\infty - x^3$ comes from even *with* abuse.

Comment: "We need to find what value limx→0⌊f(x)⌋ equals irrespective of the function f(x), as long as it satisfies limx→0f(x)x2=2"  Right.  ANd if $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(x)}{x^2}=2$ then there is a s $\delta$ where $|x|<\delta$ means $0 < f(x) < 1$.  We don't know what $f$ is and there is no need for $f$ to converge  But if $0<f(x)< 1$ for $|x|<\delta$ then $\lim [f(x)] = 0$.

Comment: " If f(x)=2x2 then quite obviously"  ... then quite obviously your friend is *wrong*.  Your friend said the limit does *not* exist and it *can*.  And your teacher is *confirmed*.  Your teacher can not be proven right with a single example but your friend can and has been proven wrong with one.  (Not to mention your teacher said something cogent and your friend spouted gibbering about treating infinity as though it were a number.  That is *ALWAYS* wrong. Even when it works it is wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, simply put, that an expression like $\infty^- \cdot x^3$ doesn't make sense; you won't find an actual function (meaning a function which only uses numbers and not $\infty$) which behaves like that. Even if you take a function like $f(x) = 2x^2 + (-10000) \cdot x^3$, as you approach zero, eventually the $x^3$ term will not matter anymore: it will be much smaller than the $2x^2$ term, if only the $x$ you insert is "small enough", so close enough to zero. That means that for $x$ small enough, this $f(x)$ will still be greater than $0$.

So yeah, your teacher is correct. In general, you should always be very skeptical when people use infinity like that. Without proper care, infinity doesn't actually make a whole lot of sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on my comment the counter-example given by your friend does not make any sense. You can't write expressions like $f(x) =2x^2+\infty^{-}x^3$. The usage of symbol $\infty$ is always specified by specific definitions and typical examples are expressions like $x\to\infty $ and $\lim_{x\to 0}1/x^2=\infty $.

On the other hand the correct argument goes like this. Since $f(x) /x^2\to 2$ the expression $f(x) /x^2$ is positive as $x\to 0$ and hence $f(x) >0$ as $x\to 0$. Further $$f(x) =x^2\cdot \dfrac {f(x)} {x^2}\to 0\cdot 2=0$$ and hence $f(x) <1$ as $x\to 0$. It follows that $\lfloor f(x) \rfloor =0$ as $x\to 0$ and thus $\lim_{x\to 0}\lfloor f(x) \rfloor =0$.

The expression $f(x) /x= x(f(x) /x^2)$ also tends to $0$ but is positive if $x\to 0^{+}$ and negative if $x\to 0^{-}$ and hence $\lfloor f(x) /x\rfloor =0$ if $x\to 0^{+}$ and $\lfloor f(x) /x \rfloor =-1$ as $x\to 0^{-}$ so that the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\left\lfloor \dfrac{f(x)} {x} \right\rfloor$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your teacher's argument (I sure as heck don't get your friend's), but I think it is valid.

$1 > \epsilon > 0$ and there is a $\delta$ so that $|x|< \delta$ implies $|\frac {f(x)}{x^2} - 2| < \epsilon$ so $2-\epsilon \frac {f(x)}{x^2} < 2-\epsilon$.  Thus $1 < \frac {f(x)}{x^2} < 3$ and $f(x) > 0$ and $x < \min(\delta,\frac 12)$ then

$0 < x^2 < \frac {f(x)} < 3x^2 < \frac 34$ so $0 <f(x) < \frac 34$ and $\lfloor f(x)\rfloor  = 0$ for all $x < \min(\delta, \frac 12)$.

Which means $\lim_{x\to 0}\lfloor f(x)\rfloor = 0$.

Which I think is your teacher's argument.

I can't see why your friend assumes $f(x) = 2x^2 + \infty - x^3$, which doesn't even make sense.  (What is $f(5)$?  Is it $\infty -25$?  What's that?) so I can't tell you why he is wrong other than that what he says makes no sense.

Comment: I'm guessing here but you probably didn't understand what $0^+$, $\infty^-$, etc. actually mean. Generally a number like $a^{+}$ is a number just greater than $a$, something like $a+0.000...1$ and $a^{-}$ is a number just less than $a$, something like $a-0.000...1$. What I meant by $\infty^{-}$ is that it's a number that is very large but not $\infty$. However, on second thoughts, I believe that a number like that doesn't exist.

Comment: Infinity is *NOT* a number.  $\infty^{-}$ is oxymoronic and self-contradictory.  $f(x) = 2x^2 +\infty^{-}x^3$ is meaningless and illdefined (what number is $f(5) = 50+150\infty^-$?).   Your friend is more than wrong.  Your friend is spouting uninterpretable gibberish.